# Searching an object inside of struct on c++

Tags: c++, cmd

I’m making a program for a library that can insert a book , shows all of the book inserted, and search for a spesific book name according to the book_code inserted by the user , i have done 2 of it but the last one ( searching ) wont run as i expected .. If anyone here can help me i would appreciate it so much. heres the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
void show_book(const Book &book );
void input_book (Book &book);
int main ()
{
  Book book[10];
  int i,x;
  char search;
  int position,found;
  cout<<"How many book you want to add = "; cin>>x;
  for (i=0; i<x; i++){
    input_book(book[i]);
  }
  for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    show_book(book[i]);
  }
//this is my searching code , im stuck here .. 
  cout<<"\n====== SEARCH ====="<<endl;
  cout <<"Enter book code = "; cin>>search;
  for (i=0; i<x; i++){
  if(book->book_code[i] == search){
    found = 1;
    position = i;
    i = x;
  }
}
  if (found != 0){
    show_book(book[position]);
  } else{
cout<<"The book is not exist";
 }
  return 0;
}
//function declaration...
void show_book(const Book &book){
  cout<<book.book_code<<" | "<<book.book_title<<endl;
}
void input_book(Book &book){
      cout << "Book code : ";cin  >> book.book_code;
      cin.ignore(1, '\n');
      cout << "Book title : " ;getline(cin, book.book_title);
}
```

[this is the output now look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evdXM.png)

Comment: variable 'search' should be std::string.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
if(book->book_code[i] == search) // accesses 1-st book, namely book[0]
```

to

```
if(book[i].book_code == search) // accesses i-th book
```

Even better if you can use `std::array` then instead of `Book book[10];` you could write:

```
std::array<Book, 10> book;
```

And noted in his comment Frank, for `search` you should use the same type as for `book_code`.

Also, that is preferable to use `bool` for `found` variable:

```
bool found = false;
```

Comment: Also, `char search;` should probably be `std::string search;`, since book codes appear to be strings.

Answer (score 1):

`found` is not initialised to 0 at start of search block.

Revised code follows

```
for (i=0,found=0;i<x && !found; ++i)
  if (book[i].book_code == search)
  {
    found = 1;
    position = i;
  }
```

Comment: oh yes thank you!! i just changed the if (book[i].book_code) and finally fixed it !